# Why doesn't CLR handle the cleanup code?

Tags: c#, .net

I have just started with the .NET framework. Today, I was taught about the `IDisposable` interface and the `dispose()` method. I was taught a few things regarding it:

`dispose()` should contain the cleanup code corresponding to an object(like closing any resources occupied by any objects - files or database connections,etc.)

I was also told that in case we don't do it in the `dispose()` method, the same could be done in the destructor, but that doesn't ensure immediate execution, and we are left to the mercy of GC.

And if at all we don't provide any cleanup code at all, the GC will forcefully terminate all connections to resources that our objects were holding. Hence, we should handle the cleanup code ourselves.

But I was curious as to why doesn't CLR handle this on it's own? It takes care of Memory Management, it takes care of Garbage Collection. So, it should very well know which Object holds onto which resource(s) and when that Object dies off. So, it should be capable of de-allocating those resources as well?

I asked a few people about it. The answer I was given was that it is because we need to close it gracefully, where as GC closes it forcefully. Is it actually the reason?

Comment: GC collects *managed* things, and `IDisposable` disposes *unmanaged* things, am I right?

Comment: Because the GC is non-deterministic. Do you really want a database connection to be open longer than it has to be?

Comment: "And if at all we don't provide any cleanup code at all, the GC will forcefully terminate all connections to resources that our objects were holding." That's not correct. The GC doesn't know about these, so it's your responsibility to handle them.

Comment: Well, the GC will **sever** those connections; the endpoints them remain open indefinitely, probably until the OS cleans up after your program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In .NET there's **much more** than managed code that the GC knows about. There's like a huge volume of unmanaged code involved: all the file handles, database connections, network sockets, ... all this is plain ol' unmanaged Win32 code. You can't even believe that in almost every single BCL function you are calling from your pretty C# application, you will be hitting like tons of unmanaged functions written in C++ (and may God forbid VB6) and buried deep into the internals of the OS itself. All those functions are allocating unmanaged memory, handles, ... The managed world doesn't know what happens there.

For example every single time you open a file (`FileStream`) you are basically calling (behind the scenes of course) the [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) unmanaged Win32 function. This function allocates an unmanaged file handle directly from the file system. .NET and the GC has strictly no way of tracking this unmanaged code and everything it does. That's why those classes implement the IDisposable interface. So that you could always wrap their instances in [using statements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) and ensure that the Dispose method is always called, even in the event of an exception, and this as soon as possible. The Dispose method will take care of calling another unmanaged function to clean the mess it created.

So basically the way you could think about the IDisposable interface is the following:

> The day when we have an operating system written in a fully managed language (something like [Midori](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midori_%28operating_system%29) for example from Microsoft Research) we will probably no longer need IDisposable as the GC will be able to completely replace it as it will have knowledge of everything that happens within this system.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Clarified a lot. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The point of `IDisposable` and `Dispose()` is that you should clean up **unmanaged** memory. That's memory .NET didn't allocate, which came from outside sources and thus the GC cannot know about it. So it cannot clean it up for you automatically. Essentially that's precisely the difference between managed and unmanaged memory ;-)

Generally you should implement `Dispose()` to clean up whatever unmanaged resources your class uses and implement the finalizer to call `Dispose()` too. The finalizer is just a safeguard, though. It will make sure that those resources get cleaned up *eventually*, if the caller forgets to dispose of your class properly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and also your comment above. Clarified a lot. But I will accept the other answer as correct one. Thanks again. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The `IDisposable` interface is there to provide you a way to clean up *un-managed* resources. The CLR only manages your *managed* resources for you.

In other words, the CLR only knows how to clean up the things that it manages. If you open connections to the rest of the system (like opening files, database connections, etc.), those are your responsibility and you need to tell the CLR how you want it to clean those up for you.

Comment: My comment is 3 seconds earlier than you :P

Answer (score 1):

The `IDisposable` interface is simply a convention to allow you to **deterministically** dispose of managed and unmanaged resources. It alone doesn't replace garbage collection or do anything involving the garbage collector itself.

It is more apparent with unmanaged resources because unless these are handled (either in a finalizer or with deterministic disposal) they will remain as a memory leak until the process ends. With managed memory, if you don't deterministically dispose of the items they will be undeterministically collected (assuming eventual eligibility for collection) by the GC, because they are managed (this is also the reason why the dispose pattern doesn't include managed items in the finalizer route).

`IDisposable` itself doesn't do anything, it is just a recognised interface (and is supported in code with the `using` keyword) that people expect to find when handling items that use consumable resources, unmanaged memory, external items, etc.

The CLR cannot possibly know when an external item is finished with. That is entirely dependent on the flow of your application. If you happen to also not know when to dispose an object, the **finalizer** syntax is useful. If you implement a finalizer on a custom class, the garbage collection process will run this finalizer just prior to final collection. This is your last chance to tidy up after yourself.

Answer (score 1):

It can only take care of memory management for .NET objects.  Any code that needs to use unmanaged resources (because it interacts with a C++ library, for example) falls outside the garbage collector's bailiwick.  All that code needs to be told when to release its resources the old-fashioned way.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way for the .Net framework (and the GC) to know how to release a un-managed resource. All it can do, is destroy the reference your managed code has to the resource. It is a lot better to actually call .Close() on a connection to your database server (thereby telling it that the connection should go back into the poll of available connection), than just destroying the reference, and letting it timeout on it's own after a set amount of seconds.

So whenever possible, use the IDisposable interface when referencing un-managed resources!

Answer (score 1):

`IDisposable` is used when you don't want the GC to handle that particular artifact. The most common example are connections, or file handles. You don't want to wait for the GC to run before releasing a file, or to close a connection to the database, since you don't know when that will happen.

Most people associate `IDisposable` with unmanaged resources, which is mostly accurate, but fail to remember that finalizers are the proper .NET way to handle those. `IDisposable` provides a way of deterministicly disposing if that is important to your program.

Answer (score 0):

we use Dispose in order to dispose unmanaged resssource as file access or connection database, because GC don't have information about this unmanaged ressource.

you can also use Finalize, but it's not performant because you save your ressource in finalisation structure, and GC pass in the end of dispose cycle by this finalisation structure, and it's not performant